# Python Turtle Checkerboard

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

def main():
     t=turtle
     s=int(input("Enter the length of each square: "))
     t.screensize(2000,2000,"lightblue")
     for row in range(0,5):
         for column in range(0,5):
             if (row+column)%2==0:
                 t.pendown()
                 t.fillcolor("black")
                 t.begin_fill()
                 square(s,row,column)
             else:
                 t.pendown()
                 t.fillcolor("white")
                 t.begin_fill()
                 square(s,row,column)
             t.goto(s+row*s,s+column*s)
def square(s,row,column):
     t=turtle
     t.penup()
     n=0
     for count in range(4):
          t.pendown()
          t.forward(s)
          t.left(90)
     t.end_fill()
     t.penup()
main()
```

So today I was given an assignment that asked me to create a 5 by 5 checkerboard. So far, I have this code which manages to create most of the checkerboard. However, I still have a mistake somewhere or I am missing some key information.

[image]

The attached picture shows what the program looks like with the error.

The program started by creating the black square, which can be seen on the bottom left corner. Then it worked up until the top right corner, where the empty space can be seen.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please describe both the expected and the observed behavior by [edit]ing your question. Without that, it'll be difficult to help you.

Comment: Are the first and second line intended to be indented differently or is that just a formatting issue that occurred when posting the question here?

Comment: @das-g

It was a simple mistake while posting the code.
I'm sorry if that confused you

Comment: No problem, just wanted to clarify to make sure this isn't the issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `t.goto(s+row*s,s+column*s)` to beginning of inner for loop does the trick.

Basically we need to move turtle to starting position first and then start drawing.

I also cleaned up the code to put redundant lines inside `square` function.
Also, added `t.penup()` so that turtle doesn't show  draw until it has reached starting position and start drawing.

```
import turtle

def main():
     t=turtle
     t.penup()
     s=int(input("Enter the length of each square: "))
     t.screensize(2000,2000,"lightblue")
     for row in range(0,5):
         for column in range(0,5):              
              t.goto(s+row*s,s+column*s)
              if (row+column)%2==0:
                   square(s,row,column,"black")
              else:
                  square(s,row,column,"white")

def square(s,row,column,color):
     t=turtle
     t.pendown()
     t.fillcolor(color)
     t.begin_fill()
     t.penup()
     n=0
     for count in range(4):
          t.pendown()
          t.forward(s)
          t.left(90)
     t.end_fill()
     t.penup()
main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's try *stamping* instead of *drawing*.  This gains us speed while simplifying our logic.  We stamp one large black square to represent the board, then stamp the white squares onto it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

SQUARES_PER_SIDE = 5
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def main():
    length = int(input("Enter the length of each square: "))

    screen = Screen()
    screen.bgcolor("lightblue")

    turtle = Turtle('square', visible=False)
    turtle.shapesize(SQUARES_PER_SIDE * length / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.stamp()  # black background

    turtle.shapesize(length / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.fillcolor("white")
    turtle.penup()

    edge = (1 - SQUARES_PER_SIDE) / 2 * length  # center of left or bottom square
    turtle.goto(edge, edge)

    for row in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
        for column in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
            if (row + column) % 2 == 0:
                turtle.stamp()  # white square

            turtle.forward(length)

        turtle.goto(edge, edge + (row + 1) * length)

    screen.exitonclick()

main()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Good use of stamp @cdlane

Answer (score 0):

Anil_M beat me to it by a few minutes; but I wanted to offer some additional code clean-up, as you've got too many needless `penup`s, `pendown`s and unnecessary parameter passing going on.

Try this:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)

def main():
     s=int(input("Enter the length of each square: "))
     for row in range(5):
         for column in range(5):
             if (row+column)%2==0:
                 color = "black"
             else:
                 color = "white"
             t.penup()
             t.goto(row*s,column*s)
             t.pendown()
             filled_square(s, color)

def filled_square(s, color):
     t.fillcolor(color)
     t.begin_fill()
     for count in range(4):
          t.forward(s)
          t.left(90)
     t.end_fill()

main()
```

Comment: Also, notice the call to the handy `speed` method, which was used to speed up the drawing to max. (And you can put back in the call to `screensize`; I was testing my code on repl.it, which doesn't support that command.)

Comment: In your code cleanup, what do you think `t = turtle` does?  It's not assigning a turtle into `t`, but rather creating an alias for the turtle package.  So, with that goal in mind, doing `import turtle as t` saves a line of code and makes what you're doing more explicit.

Comment: @cdlane good catch. I meant to initialize a specific instance via `t = turtle.Turtle()`.